# Blackberry Browser Issue.... Error encountered during XML parse: expecting a name

Tags: asp.net, blackberry-simulator

I am creating a Mobile website using Asp.net and i am facing a XML related issue in BB Browser I am using a Repeater control on my form and the data which is binding the repeater control contains ampersand "&" and it leads to an issue on BlackBerry Browser.... Below is the issue of the image.

After searching on the issue i figure out "ampersand" is the issue so how to handle "&" in data. The Repeater contains Vendor name which is " A & B " so it leads to crash

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using Server.HtmlEncode because it contains special characters in my VendorName...
Below is the code...

```
 <asp:Label ID="LabelDescription" runat="server"
               Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Description")) %>' />
```

Thanks again...